# How to get username of user's post in Django REST API instead of number?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to get username for iOS app through REST API.
I could get user number.
How do I get actual username?

The "author" should be username of user post.

http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/posts/

Result

```
HTTP 200 OK
Allow: GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

[
    {
        "author": 1,
        "title": "Test Title Post",
        "contents": "Test contents post"
  }
```

## models.py

```
User = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL

class PostDetail(models.Model):

    author           = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="PostDetail.author+") 
    title            = models.CharField('*Title', max_length=50)
    contents        = models.TextField('*Contents', max_length=450)
```

## serializer.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import PostDetail
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class PostDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   class Meta:
       model =PostDetail
       fields = (author, title, 'contents', )
```

## apis.py

```
from rest_framework import viewsets, routers
from blog.models import PostDetail
from blog.serializer import PostDetailSerializer
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model 
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class PostViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
   queryset = PostDetail.objects.all()
   serializer_class = PostDetailSerializer

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'posts', PostViewSet)
```

I expect "author": 1, to be like "author": admin,.

Answer (score 5):

You need to change your `PostDetailSerializer` to:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import PostDetail
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class PostDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

   author = serializers.CharField(source='author.username', read_only=True)

   class Meta:
       model =PostDetail
       fields = (author, title, 'contents', )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SerializerMethodField` for this task. You need to define a function to get the username of the author.

This is how you do it:

```
class PostDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    author = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
        model =PostDetail
        fields = (author, title, 'contents', )

    def get_author(self, obj):
        return obj.author.username
```

The function should be named as `get_<field_name>`.

Answer (score 0):

if you have to use for input value to, you can create the custom serializer fields

```
class ForeignKeyField(serializers.RelatedFields):

    def to_representation(self, obj):
        return obj.name
```

this fields can be use in the serializer

```
class PostDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

   author = ForeignKeyField()

   class Meta:
       model =PostDetail
       fields = (author, title, 'contents', )
```